# A word drawn such that it describes itself?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a word that describes a drawing of a word which looks like itself – almost like an autological word, but different because the word describes the image it is drawn within rather than itself.

E.g., drawing "fire" in a fiery blaze.

Here are some example picture that this word should be able to describe:

[image: fire]
<sub>(source: [cubeupload.com](https://i.cubeupload.com/ykqO3Q.png))</sub>
[image: ice]
<sub>(source: [cubeupload.com](https://i.cubeupload.com/sfI7du.png))</sub>

> As you can see, both these drawings are _________

Comment: Illuminated script.

Comment: [**Shaped Like Itself**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShapedLikeItself), probably.

Comment: _Autosymbolic_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I am struggling to find that word in dictionaries anywhere online.

Comment: This is answered at our sister site [graphicdesign](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22416/whats-the-name-for-typography-that-looks-like-the-meaning-of-its-content)

Comment: @bib The question appears there, but *autosymbolic* is a better word than *autological* (which the OP acknowledged as deficient). I'm tempted to add another answer on the GD.SE question!

Comment: @AndrewLeach You should. I also like autoglyph, mentioned there, although they tend toward the mathematical rather than the broader graphic.

Comment: @bib * autologlyph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Autologlyph

After being pointed in the right direction by bib in the [comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346608/a-word-drawn-such-that-it-describes-itself?noredirect=1#comment802226_346608), I found out about the word **autologlyph**, which seems to fit my purpose:

> An autologlyph is an image that describes itself (perhaps loosely). [<sup>[1]</sup>](http://www.segerman.org/autologlyphs/autologlyphs_talk.pdf)
>
> The name, 'autologlyph' is with reference to autological words, and they could equally be called 'autological images'. [<sup>[2]</sup>](http://www.segerman.org/autologlyphs.html)

http://www.segerman.org/autologlyphs.html

Here are some images which are given as examples, they all seem to conform to what I was wanting to be able to describe with such a word:

[image: entropy]
<sub>(source: [cubeupload.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20160916041440/http://i.cubeupload.com/MeIFk0.png))</sub>

[image: pentominoes]